# Question about transient states

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Is there a discrete time-homogeneous Markov chain $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ in which one transient state $i$ satisfies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nf^{(n)}_{ii}<\infty ?$

where $$f_{ii}^{(n)}:=\Pr(X_n=i,X_v\ne i,1\le v\le n-1\mid X_0=i),n\in \mathbb Z^+\quad .$$

Comment: A more interesting question would be is there a transient state $i$ satisfies $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty nf_{ii}^{(n)} = \infty$?

Comment: It's better to ask a new question given an answer to your old question has already been posted.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a 2-state $\{0, 1\}$ Markov chain with transition matrix $P = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$.  It is easy to verify that $f_{00}^{(1)} = \frac{1}{2}$ and $f_{00}^{(n)} = 0$ for $n \geq 2$ (because $1$ is an absorbing state).  Clearly state  $0$ is transient and
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty nf_{00}^{(n)} = \frac{1}{2} < \infty.$$