# Qustion about transient states (Continuation)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $$f_{kk}^{(n)}:=\Pr(X_n=k,X_v\ne k,1\le v\le n-1\mid X_0=k),~n\in \mathbb Z^+ .$$
Attributing to the comments of @Zhanxiong , I have added  the other two cases to the [Case 1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/628912/question-about-transient-states?noredirect=1#comment1173449_628912).

Case 1.

Is there a discrete time-homogeneous Markov chain $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ in which one transient state $i$ satisfies $  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nf^{(n)}_{ii}<\infty $?

Case 2.

Is there a discrete time-homogeneous Markov chain $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ in which one transient state $j$ satisfies $  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nf^{(n)}_{jj}=\infty $?

Case 3.

Is there a discrete time-homogeneous Markov chain $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ in which two distinct transient states $i$ and $j$, $i$ satisfies $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nf^{(n)}_{ii}<\infty $ and $j$ satisfies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nf^{(n)}_{jj}=\infty $?

Comment: I refer you to study Example 8.13 in *Probability and Measure* (3rd ed.) by Patrick Billingsley.